# When a cell is being populated through a formula in excel, is there a way to freeze the populated data (prevent it from getting updated)?

Tags: excel-formula, automation, excel-tables

I am working on automating some fields in a table in excel. I want to automatically add a 'Block Date' when the status is change to 'Blocked' in following table structure.

[sample table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlPxz.png)

I am using this excel formula for it: **=IF(B3="Blocked",TODAY(),"")**
But with every new day, the date value in 'Block Date' column updates to the current date (because it uses TODAY() function), which I don't want to happen. If I change the status to 'Blocked' on 17 November, then 'Block Date' should be 17 November, but with above formula its getting updated everyday. Is there any way to freeze the date once added?

Comment: Only by VBA. A formula will recalculate.